# Swift 5 Create 3D Array of Doubles And Pass To C Function

Tags: arrays, c, swift

**I need to call a legacy C function (from swift) that expects a 3D array of Doubles as an argument.** I am fairly new to Swift and have begun converting a large ObjC and C code base written for iOS and Mac over to Swift. The C code does a lot of complex astronomical math and for which Swift is just too cumbersome. I will not convert those, but I need to use them from Swift

The C function is declared like this and the .H file is visible to swift:

```
void readSWEDayData(double dData[DATA_ROWS_PER_DAY][NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS][NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PLANET]);
```

The Constants used in the declaration are defined to be:

```
DATA_ROWS_PER_DAY = 1
NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS = 35
NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PLANET = 4
```

I am struggling with declaring the array of doubles in a way that Swift will allow to be passed to the C function. I've tried several approaches.

**First Approach:**

I declare the array and call it like so:

```
var data = Array(repeating: Double(EPHEMERIS_NA), count:Int(DATA_ROWS_PER_DAY * NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS * NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PLANET))
readSWEDayData(&data)
```

I get this error: ***Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<((Double, Double, Double, Double),...***

**Second Approach:**

If I declare the array this way:

```
var data = [(Double, Double, Double, Double)](repeating: (EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA), count: Int(NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS))
readSWEDayData(&data)
```

I get this error: ***Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<(Double, Double, Double, Double)>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<((Double, Double, Double, Double),***

So, how the heck does one declare a 3D Array in Swift of a specific size so that it can be passed to a C Function?

Comment: And you just want to pass an array full of `EPHEMERIS_NA`, right?

Comment: Yes. EPHEMERIS_NA is simply an initializer value (-99999.0). Bottom line... I need a way to declare an array of Fixed size and pass it. Swift (a rather stupid, wank language that insists on being my nanny and which I find annoying in many ways) doesn't appear to have a way to declare multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Note that this is not because Swift does not have a way to declare multi-dimensional arrays (it does). It's simply because Swift doesn't interop with C very well, and I do agree that Swift's C interoperability is quite lacking, but it's rather unjustified to say that Swift itself is a stupid language just based on this... After all, a language can't do _everything_ perfectly. Swift's main focus is not about C-interop, after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Swift 5 lacks support for interoperability with C language multi-dimensional Arrays of fixed size except via tuples of explicitly declared structure **(See Sweeper's answer above)** and which is something I wish to avoid to keep my code flexible for future changes to the C Library being used, I opted to write a wrapper for the C function and make it appear to Swift as a 1 dimensional array.

This was necessary because the Constants used in the C Code change when readSWEDayData increases the array sizes to support additional elements and tuple declarations like this:

```
let Double4x35 = Tuple35<(Double, Double, Double, Double)>
```

will DEFINITELY break in a way that will be hard to find:

So my C wrapper function looks like so:

```
void readSWEDayDataForSwift(double *dData) {
    readSWEDayData((double (*)[NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS][NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PLANET])dData);
}
```

Making it easy to call it from Swift like so:

```
    var data = Array(repeating: Double(EPHEMERIS_NA), count:Int(DATA_ROWS_PER_DAY * NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS * NUM_ELEMENTS_PER_PLANET))
```

I was surprised that this far into Swift's evolution there is no better way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

The function needs an `UnsafeMutablePointer` to a 35-tuple of things, where each of those things are 4-tuples of `Double`s. Yes, C *arrays* translate to tuples in Swift, because Swift doesn't have fixed size arrays. You could do:

```
var giantTuple = (
    (EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA),
    (EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA),
    (EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA),
    // 32 more times...
)
readSWEDayData(&giantTuple)
```

But I don't think you'd like that. You can create an array, and use some pointer magic to convert that to a tuple, as discussed in this [Swift Forums post](https://forums.swift.org/t/convert-an-array-of-known-fixed-size-to-a-tuple). In fact, that post is highly relevant to your situation.

To save some typing, we can write some type aliases first:

```
typealias Tuple35<T> = (T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T)
typealias Double4x35 = Tuple35<(Double, Double, Double, Double)>
```

Then we can do:

```
var giantTuple = Array(repeating: (EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA), count: NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS).withUnsafeBytes { p in
    p.bindMemory(to: Double4x35.self)[0]
}

readSWEDayData(&giantTuple)
```

This works because tuples and arrays have essentially the same "layout" in memory.

Note that I "cheated" a little bit here, since `DATA_ROWS_PER_DAY` is 1, you can just create one such `giantTuple`, and get a pointer to it. However, if it is greater than 1, you'd have to do something like:

```
var giantTuples = Array(repeating:
                        Array(repeating: (EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA, EPHEMERIS_NA), count: NUM_PLANET_ELEMENTS).withUnsafeBytes { p in
                            p.bindMemory(to: Double4x35.self)[0]
                        },
                        count: DATA_ROWS_PER_DAY)

readSWEDayData(&giantTuples)
```

To convert from the giant tuple back to an array, you can do something like this:

```
// converting the first giantTuples in "giantTuples" as an example
let arrayOf4Tuples = asCollection(giantTuples[0], Array.init)
let finalArray = arrayOf4Tuples.map { asCollection($0, Array.init) }

// these are adapted from the Swift forum thread
// you'll need two of these, because you have 2 types of tuples
// yes, working with C arrays is hard :(
func asCollection<T, E>(_ tuple: Tuple35<E>, _ perform: (UnsafeBufferPointer<E>)->T) -> T {
  return withUnsafeBytes(of: tuple) { ptr in
    let buffer = ptr.bindMemory(to: (E.self))
    return perform(buffer)
  }
}
func asCollection<T, E>(_ tuple: (E, E, E, E), _ perform: (UnsafeBufferPointer<E>)->T) -> T {
  return withUnsafeBytes(of: tuple) { ptr in
    let buffer = ptr.bindMemory(to: (E.self))
    return perform(buffer)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the work on this but the reason the original code uses Defined values such as DATA_ROWS_PER_DAY is because these constants can and DO get changed from time to time, and I would rather NOT have to go around looking for places where things like Tuple35<T> = (T,T,T,T, ....) are hard coded like that. Isn't there some more elegant and future proof approach than Tuple35? That was why I was originally trying to create a one dimensional array of the proper size. Perhaps I need to create C wrapper to the other C function that only wants a 1 dimensional array and call that from Swift.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo Yes, I would suggest you create a C wrapper taking a `double *` (not a fixed sized array!), if that is an option. It would be much easier to call from Swift. There's not really a future-proof way to do this in Swift now or in the near future. See [this comment](https://forums.swift.org/t/convert-an-array-of-known-fixed-size-to-a-tuple/31432/5). And what do you mean these constants change from time to time? I thought this was legacy code?

Comment: It IS legacy C code and which is part of a rather LARGE C library of Astronomy functions I wrote and which there is NO WAY I will convert to Swift. Swift is just too cumbersome and not great for doing complex Math. So, those constants DO change from time to time when I extend it to support more planetary elements or astronomical bodies.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for others..Hoping will help.
I got a similar problem, but hope can save time for other.
I had to pass down:

- path (from String to char *)
- title (from String to char *)
- columns ([String] to array of char *)
- a counter

to sum up I had to call "C" function:

bool OpenXLSXManager_saveIn(const char  * cFullPath,
const char  * sheetName,
char *const columnTitles[],
double *const values[],
int columnCount);

1. I started from excellent:
   // https://oleb.net/blog/2016/10/swift-array-of-c-strings/
2. expanded a bit:

   ```
    public func withArrayOfCStringsAndValues<R>(
    _ args: [String],
    _ values: [[Double]],

    _ body: ([UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?]  , [UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>?]  ) -> R ) -> R {

    var cStrings = args.map { strdup($0) }
    cStrings.append(nil)

    let cValuesArrr = values.map { (numbers: [Double]) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Double> in

        let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.allocate(capacity: numbers.count)
        for (index, value) in numbers.enumerated() {
            pointer.advanced(by: index).pointee = value
        }

        return pointer
    }

    defer {
        cStrings.forEach { free($0) }

        for pointer in cValuesArrr{
            pointer.deallocate()
        }
    }

    return body(cStrings, cValuesArrr)
   ```

   }
3. so I can call:

func passDown(

```
    filePath: String,
    sheetName:
    String,
    colNames: [String],
    values: [[Double]]
) -> Bool
```

{
let columnCount = Int32(colNames.count)
return withArrayOfCStringsAndValues(colNames, values) {

```
    columnTitles, values in
    
    let retval = OpenXLSXManager_saveIn(filePath, sheetName, columnTitles, values, columnCount)
    return retval
}
```

}

(SORRY for formatting, S.O. formatter has BIG issues ..)